# Understanding type inferrence in Scala

Tags: scala, methods

I wrote the following simple program:

```
import java.util.{Set => JavaSet}
import java.util.Collections._

object Main extends App {
    def test(set: JavaSet[String]) = ()

    test(emptySet()) //fine
    test(emptySet) //error
}
```

**[*DEMO*](http://ideone.com/YtnGBy)**

And was really surprised the the final line `test(emptySet)` was not compiled. Why? What is the difference between `test(emptySet())`? I thought in Scala we could omit parenthesis freely in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Method Conversions](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-conversions) in Scala specification:

> The following four implicit conversions can be applied to methods which are not applied to some argument list.
>
> Evaluation
>
> A parameterless method m
>   of type => T is always converted to type T by evaluating the expression to which m is bound.
>
> Implicit Application
>
> If the method takes only implicit parameters, implicit arguments are passed following the rules here.
>
> Eta Expansion
>
> Otherwise, if the method is not a constructor, and the expected type pt
>   is a function type (Ts′)⇒T′, eta-expansion is performed on the expression e.
>
> Empty Application
>
> Otherwise, if e
>   has method type ()T, it is implicitly applied to the empty argument list, yielding e().

The one you want is "Empty Application", but it's only applied if none of the earlier conversions are, and in this case "Eta Expansion" happens instead.

EDIT: This was wrong and @Jasper-M's comment is right. No eta-expansion is happening, "Empty Application" is just inapplicable to generic methods currently.

Comment: But why is the type inferred in `test(emptySet)` - `JavaSet[Nothing]`?

Comment: From the error message, it isn't. If you mean that IDEA shows this type, it's wrong. You can't trust IDEA's shown errors and inferred types when typing, always try to actually build the code first.

Comment: Just read your report. Therefore, the second case should have worked just as well, right?

Comment: Yes (unless I am misunderstanding something).

Comment: Well strictly speaking, `emptySet` does not have method type `()JavaSet[T]`, but method type `[T]()JavaSet[T]`.

Comment: Oops. Of course you are right, and my answer is wrong because I managed to confuse the reported type with `() => JavaSet[T]` (despite looking at it many times). There is no eta-expansion here and so no bug (but perhaps a place for improvement).